# Exporting data from Unicode DB to Non-Unicode DB

Tags: database, unicode

So, I have 2 databases A & B. A is Unicode database and B is non-unicode. I am going to send some data from Unicode database A to non-unicode database B. I do not have any multi-byte data in database A.

I am sure I do not need to worry in this case. But still for a precaution, is there any issues I might end up upon going ahead? (There is no scope of having multi-byte data in future)

Comment: By *multi-byte*, I assume you mean characters with code-points higher than 127, i.e. non-ASCII characters? And, what kind of databases are we talking about here? MySQL? Access? UniData?

Comment: Thanks for commenting on the old thread. Though, we didnt worried and moved with the integration, I would love to get some thoughts. DB is oracle.

Comment: Okay. In that case, I might like to hear your thoughts on how it went; Probably, this question would have received more feedback on [sf].

Comment: Indeed you are right. But on not receiving any responses anywhere I removed the question(thought may be the question was absurd or something). So, about our integration, we are simply inserting the data from unicode db to non-unicode for now. I know of in future unicode gets languages like Chinese, Japanese,  we might need so alternatives. But as of now, its going fine.